# USB Mass storage, wec2013

Tags: windows-ce, usb-mass-storage

How to expose SD card in PC using USB Mass Storage Function using WEC2013, which I tried only to get the SD card unmounted from device but not getting mounted in PC?

Comment: We're missing a lot of details here.  What processor architecture?  What BSP?  What's included in the build from the catalog?  Are you seeing any debug messages?  Did you build a debug OS image?  Are you seeing any data aborts?  There's zero chance we can help without you providing details of what you've done to try to get it to work and what the exact results of those attempts have been.

Comment: and what and all sysgen components you have selected? whether you are able to see device internal (storage RAM) memory as mass storage on PC? and, there is no need to unmount the SD from device.